# If I restart crond, will scripts get interrupted?

Tags: crontab

I am changing my /etc/crontab file. 
When I execute

```
service crond restart
```

will my jobs/scripts that just begun executing by crond be terminated or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, they will not be terminated. I tested on Ubuntu (using Vixie Cron).

Your jobs PPIDs will become `1` after you do `service cron restart`.